# Instantiating LocationService in OnNavigatedToAsync causes app to hang

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, template10

I'm currently writing a location-aware MVVM app using **UWP** and **Template10**. As part of this app, I'm displaying a map page which uses the **MapControl** and this needs to show the user's current location.

I'm trying to leverage the **LocationService** which is part of the Template10 framework (although this service is not currently included in the NuGet package). The problem I have is that I cannot call into this service to get the user's current location in the **OnNavigatedToAsync** method of the page, because of the constraint mentioned in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-and-checklist-for-detecting-location), i.e.:

> Call the RequestAccessAsync before accessing the user’s location. At
>   that time, your app must be in the foreground and RequestAccessAsync
>   must be called from the UI thread. Until the user grants your app
>   permission to their location, your app can't access location data.

This is because the user is presented with a dialog box asking permission to use the device's location - but as we are not on the UI thread, the app just hangs.

Is there a way to call another method (which would call into the **LocationService**) once the page has completed loading and is ready to go? I've tried hooking in a command call from the page's Loaded event, but the same problem occurs there too.

Comment: Have you actually tried calling RequestAccessAsync  in  OnNavigatedToAsync ?  Because that's where other examples do it. I'm not familiar with this T10 service though.

Comment: If you are using a ViewModel then create a method like LoadState() and then call that method inside the OnNavigatedTo() method of the page.

Comment: @Tseng. I presume you've edited the title, but you've removed the context which was to do with Template10 and the LocationService. I wasn't "forcing" anything into the title, I was framing it in a way that I hoped would elicit a response. Now the title is just bland and meaningless.

Comment: No, I was not removing the context. The tag is still there in the section. There is already a [tag:template10] and people who are proficient with it, watch this tag same as other people have their favorite tags they are watching at.You can read the correct usage of tags at http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. Be aware that StackOverflow is **not** a **discussion forum** where it's common to put "tags" into thread title. SO is different and the tags are visible on both the question page and on the overview page

Comment: As @grace-feng-msft points out below, we are in the UI thread. However, as commented below, the sample app she mentions **is** hanging as described, when the permission dialog is displayed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 's suggestion above worked for me.  I was getting a freeze on the dialog calling permissions checker from my map custom renderer.  I removed that and put it in a BeginInvokeOnMainThread in the view done on first display of the view -- and freeze stopped happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to leverage the LocationService which is part of the Template10 framework (although this service is not currently included in the NuGet package).

What you mean by this `LocationService`? I couldn't find any document about this. I just used [Geolocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225534) in the doc your provided to test your problem, and I can't reproduce it.

> This is because the user is presented with a dialog box asking permission to use the device's location - but as we are not on the UI thread, the app just hangs.

No, it is said the `RequestAccessAsync` method must be called before accessing the user’s location and must be called from the UI thread, if you call this `RequestAccessAsync` method in the `OnNavigatedToAsync`, it is called from UI thread, the app will not hang.

Here is my sample, I created an empty hamburger template 10 project, and in the Detail page:

Firstly adding 4 `TextBlock` to show the status and position in xaml:

```
<!--  content  -->
<ScrollViewer Padding="12,8,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="You passed:" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Value, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=DesigntimeValue}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Status,Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Latitude, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Longitude, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Accuracy, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Part of code in the ViewModel:

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
    Value = (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value))) ? suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString() : parameter?.ToString();

    StartTracking();

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async void StartTracking()
{
    // Request permission to access location
    var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

    switch (accessStatus)
    {
        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;
            _geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = _desireAccuracyInMetersValue };
            Geoposition pos = await _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask(token);
            UpdateLocationData(pos);
            // Subscribe to PositionChanged event to get updated tracking positions
            _geolocator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;

            // Subscribe to StatusChanged event to get updates of location status changes
            _geolocator.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;
            break;

        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
            break;

        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
            break;
    }
}
```

Other codes you can refer to the official [Geolocation sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation).

> Is there a way to call another method (which would call into the LocationService) once the page has completed loading and is ready to go?

I think the problem is you need to check out what exactly cause your app hang. If it is the problem with `LocationService`, could you please post the document of this service in the comment?

**Update:**

If you read the source code of this `LocationService`, you can find it packaged the `Geolocation` APIs into one service, if you use code `var locationService = new LocationService();var pos = locationService.Position;`, then most of the code in the `StartTracking()` method are useless, they just create another `Geolocator`, and try to get position, get notification when position changed again as the service does. **But** `RequestAccessAsync` is still needed, and it must be called before you new a instance of `LocationService`, so you can code like this:

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
    Value = (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value))) ? suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString() : parameter?.ToString();
    var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
    var locationService = new LocationService();
    var pos = locationService.Position;
    //StartTracking();
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Just tested, it works fine.

Comment: The LocationService is here: [link](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Template10%20(Services)/LocationService)

There's no documentation for it, and I've included it locally in order to use it.

You're right that the above code works, so there must be more to this than meets the eye. I'll do some more experimentation and post back.

Comment: If you copy the three files in the LocationService from Template10 and include them in your project, then add the following two lines to the OnNavigatedToAsync method, above the StartTracking call, it will hang.

`var locationService = new LocationService();
var pos = locationService.Position;`

(Don't forget to uninstall the app before running it again to remove the location permission.)

Comment: @grahama, I updated my answer, please have a check;).

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work. However I'm still very puzzled, as if you put the RequestAccessAsync call in the constructor of the LocationHelper, like this `GeolocationAccessStatus = Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync().AsTask<GeolocationAccessStatus>().Result;`, and make the rest of the constructor contingent on `GeolocationAccessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed`, it still locks up. I guess I'll have to go with this solution for the time being, but I was hoping I'd be able to improve the LocationService to encapsulate the call to request access.